# ¿De donde viene la palabra "chanchi"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa

En el diccionario de la lengua, [**chachi**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8RudNPJ%7C8RwR0H6) remite a [**chanchi**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8XeOJWr) que aparece  definido sencillamente como:

> *Esp.* Estupendo, muy bueno.

sin más indicaciones.

¿De dónde procede? ¿Se usa fuera de España?

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más contexto al respecto? ¿Dónde la has leído?

Comment: @fedorqui es una interjección sin más, aquí en Andalucía se usa mucho "chachi" y en Castilla-La Mancha he oído bastante la variante "chanchi". Un ejemplo muy sencillo: "-¿Nos vamos al cine? -¡Chachi!"

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ah, sí, _chachi_ sí lo he oído. Para tirar del hilo: [http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-del-termino-chachi/](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-del-termino-chachi/) si lo dice _El listo que todo lo sabe_, va a misa.

Answer (score 1):

Como señala **Fedorqui**, aunque no lo ponga como respuesta, la pregunta ya ha sido contestada en [el blog de *Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe*](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-del-termino-chachi/) y si lo dice "El listo que todo lo sabe", va a misa:

> De una parte, el origen por el que más expertos y etimólogos consultados apuestan es el que dice que ‘chachi’ proviene del término en caló (lengua utilizada por el pueblo gitano) ‘chachipé / chachipen’ cuyo significado es ‘verdad’ y ‘realidad’. Parece ser que se utilizaba en expresiones como ‘chachi que sí’ que venía a significar ‘verdad que sí’, ‘claro que sí’. Lo que no queda demasiado claro es cómo pasó de chachipén a chanchi y de esta finalmente a chachi y pasar a significar ‘estupendo, muy bueno’, aunque nada es imposible en nuestro idioma en el que es frecuente encontrase de tanto en tanto con alguna ‘pirueta semántica’ como es el caso del término ‘mamarracho’ (del que os hablé días atrás).
>
> El otro posible origen del término ‘chachi’ nos lleva hasta Andalucía, concretamente a la provincia de Cádiz, y lo sitúa en los tiempos de la posguerra española (coincidiendo con la Segunda Guerra Mundial) una época de carestía y en el que el contrabando (también conocido como estraperlo) que se realizaba desde Gibraltar estaba a la orden del día. Muchos eran los productos de primera necesidad que se traía desde este territorio perteneciente al Reino Unido (siendo el Primer Ministro Británico el famoso Winston Churchill).
>
> Según apuntan, quienes defienden el origen gaditano del término, eran de tan buena calidad esos productos introducidos a través del mercado negro que se referían a los mismos con el apellido del mandatario inglés: Churchill, siendo pronunciado como ‘charchil’ y que con el tiempo derivó en ‘chachi’ (otra ‘pirueta semántica’).
>
> Aunque el primer posible origen de chachi es el que defienden más expertos en etimología, este segundo es el que gusta y se comparte más, teniendo en cuenta que tiene a toda una provincia tras de sí que defiende esa procedencia ...

Sólo falta aclarar si se utiliza fuera de España, como se plantea en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta parcial.

No había oído esto así en México o EEUU.  Chequeé el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8RudNPJ|8RwR0H6) y dice

> 1. adj. Esp. chanchi. U. t. c. adv.

Es decir, se usa en España.

(¿Qué es "u.t.c"?)

Comment: _Usado también como..._ nótese que si en el DRAE pones el ratón encima de estas abreviaciones, aparece su explicación.